# Alignment of nodes in TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

I am trying to draw a diagram in Tikz. Its structure is the same as the one of a general timeline arrow. I am having troubles aligning the nodes (that is, the written text entailed in the nodes). More precisely, the last notes - the nodes with the IPA text - do not align and are one closer to the main arrow than the one before it. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa} % IPA symbols

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->, thick] (1, 0) --(12, 0);
        \draw [thick] (1,.2) --(1, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (3,.2) --(3, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (5,.2) --(5, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (6.5,.2) --(6.5, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (7.5,.2) --(7.5, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (9,.2) --(9, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (10,.2) --(10, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (11,.2) --(11, -.2);
        \draw [thick] (1,-.2) node[below]{\small{Plosive}};
        \draw [thick] (3,-.2) node[below]{\small{Frikative}};
        \draw [thick] (5,-.2) node[below]{\small{Sonoranten}};
        \draw [thick] (5,-.6) node[below]{\small{(r, l, $\underbrace{\text{m, n}}_\text{Nasale}$)}};
        \draw [->, thick] (4.375, -1.2) --(4.375, -1.8);
        \draw [thick] (4.65, -1.2) --(4.65, -1.92);
        \draw [->, thick] (4.65, -2.3) --(4.65, -2.6);
        \draw [thick] (4.375, -1.8) node[below]{\footnotesize{Vibrant}};
        \draw [thick] (4.65, -2.6) node[below]{\footnotesize{Lateral}};
        \draw [thick] (6.5, -.2) node[below]{\small{\textipa{j}}};
        \draw [thick] (7.5,-.2) node[below]{\small{\textipa{i, y, u}}};
        \draw [thick] (9,-.2) node[below]{\small{\textipa{e, \o, o}}};
        \draw [thick] (10,-.2) node[below]{\small{\textipa{E, O}}};
        \draw [thick] (11,-.2) node[below]{\small{\textipa{a, A}}};
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the different nodes have different heights, so their baselines are at different distances from the "axis". There are a couple of ways you can fix that, for example setting the same `text height` for all the nodes (e.g. `node[below,text height=2ex] ...`). Perhaps easier though, is to just add a `\strut` in each node (e.g. `node [below]{\strut ...}`).

A couple of other comments:

- `\small` is not a macro that takes an argument, it is a switch that influences the following text within the same group. Hence, it should be used as `{\small text}`, not `\small{text}`.
- I don't think the `minipage` does anything useful here, so I would just remove it. Also the `\\` after `\end{tikzpicture}` is not needed.
- The code can be drastically simplified by using a loop, see example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa} % IPA symbols

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [->, thick] (1, 0) --(12, 0);
   \foreach [count=\i] \x/\txt in {1/Plosive,3/Frikative,5/Sonoranten,6.5/\textipa{j},7.5/\textipa{i, y, u},9/\textipa{e,\o,o},10/\textipa{E, O},11/\textipa{a, A}}
     \draw (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2) node[below,font=\small] (n\i) {\strut\txt};

   \node [below,font=\small] (n3-1) at (n3.south) {(r, l, $\underbrace{\text{m, n}}_\text{Nasale}$)};
   \draw [thick,->] ([xshift=1.8em,yshift=3.3ex]n3-1.south west) -- ++(0,-1.4cm) node[below,font=\footnotesize] {Lateral};
   \draw [thick,->] ([xshift=0.9em,yshift=3.3ex]n3-1.south west) -- ++(0,-0.6cm) node[below,fill=white,inner sep=3pt,font=\footnotesize] {Vibrant};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also really appreciate the compact way of writing the code.